# Anchor tag with jQuery function doesn't initiate more than once

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I have an anchor tag

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit"> <div class="text">original</div><div class="active-text hidden">hide</div></a>
```

with a query function linked

```
//activate editing
$('.edit').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.text').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.active-text').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).prev('span').attr('contenteditable', 'true').addClass('active-editing');
});

//deactivate editing
$('.edit-tag.noli .active-text').on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.text').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).parent().find('.active-text').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).prev('span').attr('contenteditable', 'false').removeClass('active-editing');
});
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot click this link more than once?

Comment: You are nesting click handlers, why???

Comment: I can un nest them. Not good practice?

Comment: What happen when you click the second time? You fire two handlers. What happen when you click third time, etc... So no, don't nest handlers

Comment: Ok thanks for your input @A.Wolff, much appreciated! I will fix and update the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this,

```
    var flag = true;
$('.edit').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.text').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.active-text').toggleClass('hidden');
    if (flag) {
        $(this).prev('span').attr('contenteditable', 'true').addClass('active-editing');
    } else {
        $(this).prev('span').attr('contenteditable', 'false').removeClass('active-editing');
    }
    flag = false;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z47Fk/13/)

Comment: Thanks @anoop-joshi! The if conditional is a great solution! much appreciation!

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this???

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit">show-hide</a>
<div class="text">original</div>
<div class="active-text" style="display:none;">hide</div>

$('.edit').on("click", function () {
    //since void(0) no need for prevent default
    $('.text').toggle();
    $('.active-text').toggle();
    $(this).prev('span').attr('contenteditable', 'true').addClass('active-editing');
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/z47Fk/15/)